# a newbie at its first login performance.. help required

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

When I click the login button, it executes the code in the `else` instead of the `if`.

Can someone help me with what I`m missing?

Here's my code:

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=COMPAQ-PC-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Gym;Integrated Security=True");
        string SQL = "select username,password from login where username like '" + tbUserName.Text + "' and password like '" + tbPassword.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, cn);
        if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            cn.Open();
        }
        int roweffect = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (roweffect > 0)
        {
            Form2 login_Success = new Form2();
            login_Success.ShowDialog();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please provide the correct username and password", "Invalaid Username OR Password", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }

    }
```

Comment: the roweffect variable gets the value -1.. i dont know why

Comment: A select statement in a ExecuteNonQuery call will always return -1 because it hasnt affected any rows.

Comment: INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE affect rows.  select simply looks at data.

Comment: Insert, delete, update statements. Note that "show me data" is not the same as "how much data did you CHANGE". Use ExecuteQuery / ExecuteScalar, not ExecuteNonQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using a `Using` statement, and `ExecuteScalar` is probably better

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(
            @"Data Source=COMPAQ-PC-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Gym;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
        string.Format(@"select username,password 
                        from login where username like '{0}' 
                        and password like '{1}'", 
                            tbUserName.Text, tbPassword.Text), cn);
    cn.Open();
    if (cmd.ExecuteScalar() == null)
        MessageBox.Show("Please provide the correct username and password", 
            "Invalaid Username OR Password", 
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    else
    {
        Form2 login_Success = new Form2();
        login_Success.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: executescalar() is better or executequery()??

Comment: why have you used using before sqlconnection?

Comment: ExecuteQuery will return -1 (I believe) unless you do an update. ExecuteScalar returns the first column of the first row, and is a good test to see if your query has results. If you use SqlConection in a Using statement, it'll be correctly disposed and the connection object returned to the connection pool.

Answer (score 2):

ExecuteNonQuery does not return the number of rows for SELECT statements.
[ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx)

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE
>   statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the
>   command. When a trigger exists on a
>   table being inserted or updated, the
>   return value includes the number of
>   rows affected by both the insert or
>   update operation and the number of
>   rows affected by the trigger or
>   triggers. For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1. If
>   a rollback occurs, the return value is
>   also -1.

Instead you can try using ExecuteScalar and checking if the result is null.

Answer (score 0):

use cmd.ExecuteQuery();